# How to check prefix of variables in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I want to find how many resource is there in an RDF but I can't find any tutorial to explain how can I check the prefix of variables in my SPARQL.

I have tried this:

```sql
select count(?x) where {
  res:?x ?p ?v
}
```

but it has syntax error. I am using virtuoso for DBPedia

Comment: When you use `?` it is  variable. You can't assign a prefix to it. What exactly are you trying to extract?

Comment: I want to find the number of entities in DBPedia which are in subject role of any triple and also their URIs have prefix `res:<http://dbpedia.org/resource/>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **strstarts(string,prefix)** to check whether **string** begins with **prefix**.  You can use the **str** function to get the string representation of a IRI, including IRIs generated from prefixes.  E.g., if you have **prefix ex: <http://example.org/>**, then **ex:** by itself is a legal IRI, and **str(ex:)** produces **"http://example.org/"**.  That means that you can check whether an IRI that is the value of a variable **?x** begins with some particular prefix **p:** by doing **strstarts(str(?x),str(p:))**.  Then you can filter on that, or count it, etc.

Here's an example that binds **?thing** to a few different values, some of which begin with the **dbpedia-owl:** prefix:

```sql
select * where {
   values ?thing { dbpedia-owl:a dbpedia-owl:b dbpprop:c }
   bind( strstarts(str(?thing),str(dbpedia-owl:)) as ?startsWithDBpediaOwl )
}
```

[SPARQL results (a and b get true, c gets false)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20*%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20values%20%3Fthing%20%7B%20dbpedia-owl%3Aa%20dbpedia-owl%3Ab%20dbpprop%3Ac%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20bind%28%20strstarts%28str%28%3Fthing%29%2Cstr%28dbpedia-owl%3A%29%29%20as%20%3FstartsWithDBpediaOwl%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

You can filter on that too, and then count the results:

```sql
select (count(*) as ?n) where {
   values ?thing { dbpedia-owl:a dbpedia-owl:b dbpprop:c }
   filter strstarts(str(?thing),str(dbpedia-owl:))
}
```

[SPARQL results (2)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%28count%28*%29%20as%20%3Fn%29%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20values%20%3Fthing%20%7B%20dbpedia-owl%3Aa%20dbpedia-owl%3Ab%20dbpprop%3Ac%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20filter%20strstarts%28str%28%3Fthing%29%2Cstr%28dbpedia-owl%3A%29%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)